# How to change in runtime the catalog name to all objects in all queries using NHibernate with MS SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I have an application (web) on which each user logged on has a exclusive catalog (working like a private database - *please don't ask me why, the project requirements isn't discussed here*).

So, I need to tell NHiberante `ISession` (or something similar escope) which is the catalog name and schema name to build correctly the full objects names, so: `catalog.schema.table`, `catalog.schema.procedure`, ...

Look that I'm ***avoiding to have a pool*** of Session Factories, I prefer to have ***only one SessionFactory*** and access individual catalogs telling to NHibernate which to use on each `ISession` or similar.

I know that I can intercepts all SQL statements with `IInterceptor.OnPrepareStatement()`, but this approach needs to parse in runtime all statements, it isn't a good approach.

What could be others solutions ? And what is the best (performance, maintainability, ...) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried in the `IInterceptor.OnPrepareStatement()` to insert a new statement preceding the current statement to do that: `USE [TheCurrentUserCatalog]` and it works, but is that the better solution ?

Comment: When you say "exclusive catalog", do you mean a separate database for each user?

Comment: @autonomatt Yes. Catalog = database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of intercepting individual SQL statements, you can implement your own `ConnectionProvider` to issue the `use <catalog>` statement.

For example:

```
public class MyConnectionProvider : DriverConnectionProvider
{
    public override IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var connection = base.GetConnection();
        var useCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
        use.CommandText = "use " + GetCatalog();
        useCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about to define/change the schema name (in SQL SERVER) ? Does have a way without to run ALTER USER on which `DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()` event ?

Comment: I'm not following, what is the use case?

Comment: It's just a non-functional requirement, not a use case. I need to change the schema and catalog name dynamicly (in runtime) for each user.